# Handle undefined data in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below ajax call and sometimes the request stops the page from loading as the data being passed is undefined.

I there a way to put a condition to handle the request if it has values that are undefined?

Can it be wrapped with a if condition?

> newuser is not defined

```
  $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'sample.aspx,
                        data: newuser,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(data){
                         ...             
                        }  ,
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }
});
            });
```

Comment: Maybe: `data: newuser || {},`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use a pipe:

```
 $.ajax({url: 'sample.aspx',
        data: newuser || {},//continue here...
```

If your variable was not initialized, empty object will be sent instead.

That's if and only if you can handle empty "newuser" for some reason.

I'm assuming that not closed URL is just a mistake in copy-paste, and not actually part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if(newuser)
{
  $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'sample.aspx,
                        data: newuser,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(data){
                         ...             
                        }  ,
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }
});
            });

}
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/601402/in-a-specified-folder-how-can-i-recursively-delete-everything-except-mkv-and

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to handle an empty `newuser` you can try something like this:

```
if (newuser) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'sample.aspx',
    data: newuser,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
  });
}
```